# Cassandra do not launch: encountered during startup: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. Found[cassandra.yaml]

Tags: java, cassandra, cqlsh

I was using Cassandra normally last day, but after installing maven and restarting my computer, I am getting this error message when I launch CQLSH:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

And when launching this command line:

```
sudo cassandra -R
```

I have this error message:

```
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. Found[cassandra.yaml]. Please prefix the file with [file:///] for local files and [file://<server>/] for remote files. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. Found[cassandra.yaml]. Please prefix the file with [file:///] for local files and [file://<server>/] for remote files. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:100)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:268)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:147)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:132)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.applyConfig(CassandraDaemon.java:665)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:609)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:732)
22:28:18.449 [main] ERROR o.a.c.service.CassandraDaemon - Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. Found[cassandra.yaml]. Please prefix the file with [file:///] for local files and [file://<server>/] for remote files. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:80) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:100) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:268) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:147) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:132) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.applyConfig(CassandraDaemon.java:665) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:609) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:732) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
```

What is wrong with Cassandra please ?

I even uninstalled it and reinstall again without success.

I suspect that Maven installed another Java version or something ... hope you can help on this case.

```
Cassandra Version: 3.11.4

Java version:

openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

OS:
Ubuntu 16.04
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of these variables are defined in */etc/cassandra/jvm.options*. You can change the value of *cassandra.confi*g to point to the actual location of your cassandra.yaml file. It should start with *file://* to make it a valid URI.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer but unfortunatelly  this not solve the problem ... there is no `/etc/cassandra/jvm.options`, and inside the folder `/etc/cassandra/` there only empty folder: `trigger/`

Comment: Where is your cassandra.yaml file? the jvm.options can be present there also.